# Can a domain that has a website build with WordPress, be re-use outside WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a domain, and so far I used WordPress to have a momentary website, now that I want to replace it. Can WordPress be turned off, so I can deploy on the same domain?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and isn't on topic as defined here [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can! But you'll need access to your/a server and to the domain management service where your domain is currently registered.